# Business Hours In Reporting

Tags: reporting, case, administration, businesshours

Does anyone know of a way to use Business Hours for an Age variable within a report?  I did some research and finally halted when I ran across:

[SF Help Article About Support Hours](http://na4.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_supporthours.htm%20SF%20Help%20Article%20On%20Support%20Hours)

...of which the key problem I saw there was:

**You cannot include the Business Hours field in list views or reports**

Comment: Are you looking to define age by hours?

Comment: Report on BUSINESS HOURS that have passed since creation basically.

Comment: Since I don't know exactly how you'll use this, I'm wondering if you couldn't use some kind of variation on the following post: [Formula for finding business days since last interaction](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10636/formula-for-finding-business-days-since-last-interaction) once you modified it to get hours instead of days.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be asking specifically about Cases, but this app has some logic you can probably borrow: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ccNEAQ

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution to your problem would be to create a custom object with fields that contain your business hours (I'd anticipate one field for each day of the week, but that may be more than is needed). Don't forget that you'll need at least one or more fields to hold holidays too.

If you make the object and fields reportable, I'd think you should be able to calculate the number of business hours that will have passed since the dateTime creation of anything you want to look at.